# Create ionic4 project after ionic5 release

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

As ionic5 is now released, so now when I use this command `ionic start myApp blank --type=angular` ionic5 app is created, I can confirm this from `ionic info` command, I am wondering how can I create ionic4 project. The reason behind creating ionic4 project is I have one app in ionic3 and I want to upgrade that app to first in ionic4 and then to ionic5 instead of directly going to latest one because I don't yet know the breaking changes in ionic5 yet and I haven't yet worked on it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I got ionic4 app by first creating project with command `sudo ionic start myApp blank --type=angular` and then when project was created, then using `sudo npm i @ionic/angular@^4.0.0` inside app directory to update the ionic info, this can be confirmed both via **package.json** and **ionic info command**